# error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&' first type int and second type boolean

Tags: java

I am new to java and I really enjoy this new learning experience.
I got assigned a task where we have to create a simple calendar where the user needs to put a date and the program needs to tell you if it is a correct date.

However, I receive an error code that I'm using a bad operand type. I cant use an int with a boolean type. However, I do not seem to be able to find the problem.

All help and insight is very welcome

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);  // Creating the new Scanner
    
    System.out.print("Choose a day: ");            //Asking for user to introduce a day
    int day = userInput.nextInt();
    
    System.out.print("Choose a month: ");           // Asking user to introduce a month
    int month  = userInput.nextInt(); 
    
    System.out.print("Choose a year: ");            //Asking user to introduce a year
    int year  = userInput.nextInt(); 
    
    
    if ( (1<= day <= 31) && (1 <= month <= 12) && (year >= 0)){     //marking the limits of day, month and year
        System.out.println(" Congratulations, the date you introduced : " + day + month + year +"exists!!");
    } else if ( (day > 30) && (month = 2 || 4 || 6 || 9 || 10) && (year >= 0)){             //marking the months which have 30 days
        System.out.println(" Oh no, the date you introduced : " + day + month + year +" does Not exists!! You can always try again");
    }else if ( (day > 28) && (month = 2) && (year >=0)){                //marking month February
       System.out.println(" Oh no, the date you introduced : " + day + month + year +" does Not exists!! You can always try again");
    } else {
        System.out.println(" Oh no, the date you introduced : " + day + month + year +" does Not exists!! You can always try again");
    }

}
```

Comment: `1<= day <= 31` is not valid java.  You must use `1 <= day && day <= 31`.  Neither is `month = 2 || 4`, you must use `month == 2 || month == 4` etc...Please look up correct syntax, don't try to invent your own.

Comment: `month = 2` looks wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `if ( (day >= 1 && day <= 31) && (month >= 1 && month <= 12) && (year >= 0))`
Also, for every month you need to put `month == 2 || month == 4 ...`